# set fix size of an java rcp4 Part

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I prgram an application with Java and use RCP4.
Now I´d like to program an navigation Bar in my application.
The navigation Bar shoud have a fix width which shoud not be modifiable.

Can I do thas with a Part in the RCP4 application model?
I found no way to fix the size of a Part.

Answer (score 0):

If your part belongs to Part Sash Container, you should create your own renderer (Something similar to org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm)
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/173646/ may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a TrimBar?  We embedded a navigation tree into the left-side Window Trim.  TrimBar's can't be resized but will change size to accommodate what they contain (i.e. the left side trim bar's width will grow so that the tree will fit), but cannot be resized by the user.

If, however, you would like to use a Part, create a `Part Sash Container` to separate this Part from the rest of the items in your perspective and then add "NoMove" as a Tag to the `Part Sash Container`.  This prevents the sash from being resized.